# Tagging bounty award user

Tags: support, tags, bounties

In a regular question, it is assumed that comments notify the OP, even though you can explicitly tag the OP, evident by the tag suggestion/auto-fill.

I find myself wanting to message the bounty awarding user, who has placed a bounty on a buried post, where the OP may or may not be active.

But there is no autofill tag suggestion for the bounty user.

Is it implicit?